# Know any 3D game makers that work on chromebooks?

Tags: flash-develop

Ok so I make flash games using a website named scratch.mit.edu, and it used to be a downloadable program in 2013. They have had 3 major updates to the site since 2013. Understand that this site is for people ages 8 and up. It teaches you a type of flash coding with blocks. Like IF, Space key pressed, Wait 20 seconds, then change sprite 2's costume to #3. I'm not sure if any of that is a good enough base for actual coding. There are people, more professional, who have managed to use it too make 3D imaging and animations on the site and it's really amazing but I have no idea how to do that or if I want too based on the amount of lag.

So I have two questions:

One, what is the best way to learn coding without college.
 (preferably free)

Two, are there any 3D game creators that don't need coding experience and can actually work using a Samsung Chromebook?

I know i'm not a professional but I couldn't find the amatuer game developer site, if you could direct me there that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Game Development Stack Exchange. Unfortunately there are a few problems with your question. First, you are asking two questions at once. If you have more than one question, please post them separately. Second, both questions aren't really on-topic here. The first is asking us for education advise, the second for a technology recommendations. For more information about what is and is not on-topic here, please check the article ["What topics can I ask about here"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the [help center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are people, more professional, who have managed to use it too
>   make 3D imaging and animations on the site and it's really amazing but
>   I have no idea how to do that or if I want too based on the amount of
>   lag.

In theory, on any machine that you are allowed to display graphics, you can also display 3D graphics. Of course that means that if there are no tools/libraries to do the math for you, you'd have to do it yourself, which is **not** recommended for someone new to programming. Also if the software you are using does not support 3D graphics, you can still display them, but it will most likely not take advantage of the system's GPU, which means performance would be terrible.

Having said that, I've never used [scratch.mit.edu](http://scratch.mit.edu), but from what I remember it doesn't support 3D graphics, although I could be wrong.

> One, what is the best way to learn coding without college. (preferably free)

Well, the question to that always is, start programming, pick a language, pick a tool/library for making games, and start coding. You don't have to make the next big hit to learn, start by making a broken game, understand the concepts of it, and how everything should work. You could for example try [Python](https://www.python.org/), using the [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org) library, which is mean for making games.

One could also argue that you can use a graphical engine, like [Unity](https://unity3d.com/), which can take care some of the coding for you, until you are more comfortable with it.

> Two, are there any 3D game creators that don't need coding experience and can actually work using a Samsung Chromebook?

Unfortunately I've never owned a Chromebook, but I've heard it supports android apps, so maybe you can find something in the App Store? I've tried some apps in the past like [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en_GB), which is used for android development, but I've only used it for testing, never for an actual release of an app. Although that was meant for android development with Java, not the best choice for a new person.

There are plenty of tutorials online, if you search on google something like "LANG tutorials" replacing "LANG" with the language of your choice, you can get plenty of free resources. From that point, it's like a musical instrument, the more you use it, the more sense it makes. Once you feel comfortable enough, you can move to the next step.